# Simulating a large battle

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have to simulate a battle between two players. It can last from one to six rounds. Attacker can have 13 different types of spaceships, defender - additional 9 types of defence structures. The thing is I'm going to limit the simulation to 1kk units on each side, so it's going to be pretty big.

Every unit is going to be instance of the following class

```
class Unit()
{
    UInt16 id; // unit type
    Int32 structuralIntegrity;
    Int16 shieldPower;

    public Unit(UInt16 unitType, Int16 playerId)
    {
        id = unitType;
        switch (playerId)
            {
                case 0: {structuralIntegrity = player0BaseStructuralIntegrity[id]; shieldPower = player0BaseshieldPower[id];}
                case 1: {structuralIntegrity = player1BaseStructuralIntegrity[id]; shieldPower = player1BaseshieldPower[id];}
            }
    }
};
```

Arrays for unchanging values.

player1technolgies

- armour tech
- shield tech
- weapon tech

player2technolgies

- armour tech
- shield tech
- weapon tech

player1BaseStructuralIntegrity

equall to default*armour tech

And so on...

Then I would propagate two lists with each player units.

One round goes like that:

1. Pick random unit // actually I don't think it matters if it's random or not
2. Pick random target
3. If weapon power is lower than 1% of target's shield it deals no damage
4. Target's shields absorbs damage, rest of it goes to target's structural integrity
5. If target's structural integrity is lower than 30% of its initial value, it has the probability of 1-structuralIntegrity/baseStructuralIntegrity to explode
6. Check the probability of rapid fire, if it hits go to step 2
7. Go to step 1 until all units attack | NOTE! Destroyed ships - with structural integrity below 1 can still be attacked. EDIT: they also can attack this round
8. Repeat steps 1-7 for opponent.
9. Remove destroyed ships
10. Restore shields

The battle lasts for six rounds or until one side is defeated.

Lets consider an attacking fleet of 100 bombers vs 200 rocket launchers. Bombers have 95% chance to fire again after attacking rocket launcher. So every bomber will attack 96 times on average giving us 9600 attacks. Assume defender was lucky and one rocket launcher survived. He also destroyed 10 bombers. Now we have 90 bombers attacking one rocket launcher giving us another 8640 shots. Think about 100k bombers and 200k rocket launchers.

Do you have any suggestions how to improove this simulation(performance)? How many times should I run it to get believable average results?

## Update

I think I will probably stick to my simulation because even if you found a mathematical solution for this I wouldn't understand it due to my current education level.

Someone asked for more details.

Every level of correspondent technology increases initial value by 10%, but it's not important for simulation so assume both players have 0 technology. Let's consider an attacking fleet of 1 Cruiser vs 2 Missile Launchers + 1 Heavy Laser. Cruiser has 2700 structural integrity, 50 shield and 400 weaponry. I will write it as 2700:50:400

- Cruiser 2700:50:400 x1
  vs
- Missile Launcher 200:20:80 x2
- Heavy Laser 800:100:250 x1

Missile Launcher and Heavy Laser don't have rapid fire. Cruiser has 0 rapid fire against Heavy Laser and 10 against Missile Launcher giving it (10-1)/10=**0.90** probability to fire again after attacking Missile Launcher.

One possible outcome could be the following:

### round 1

**attacker fires at defender**

Cruiser with 2700:50:400 fires at Missile Laucher with 200:20:80; result is Missile Laucher with -180:0:80

Rapid Fire:

- Cruiser has rapid fire against Missile Launcher.
- dice was 0.62, comparing with 0.90: Cruiser gets another shot.

Cruiser with 2700:50:400 fires at Missile Laucher with 200:20:80; result is Missile Launcher with -180:0:80

Rapid Fire:

- Cruiser has rapid fire against Missile Launcher.
- dice was 0.09, comparing with 0.90: Cruiser gets another shot.

Cruiser with 2700:50:400 fires at Missile Launcher with -180:0:80; result is Missile Launcher with -580:0:80

Rapid Fire:

- Cruiser has rapid fire against Missile Launcher.
- dice was 0.83, comparing with 0.90: Cruiser gets another shot.

Cruiser with 2700:50:400 fires at Heavy Laser with 800:100:250; result is Heavy Laser with 500:0:250

Rapid Fire:

- Cruiser doesn't have rapid fire against Heavy Laser.

**defender fires at attacker**

Missile Laucher with -580:0:80 fires at Cruiser with 2700:50:400; result is Cruiser with 2670:0:400

Missile Laucher with -180:0:80 fires at Cruiser with 2670:0:400; result is Cruiser with 2590:0:400

Heavy Laser with 500:0:250 fires at Cruiser with 2590:0:400; result is Cruiser with 2340:0:400

**remove ships and restore shields**

Cruiser still has integrity, restore its shield.

Missile Laucher lost all its integrity, remove it from battle.

Missile Laucher lost all its integrity, remove it from battle.

Heavy Laser still has integrity, restore its shield.

### round 2

**attacker fires at defender**

Cruiser with 2340:50:400 fires at Heavy Laser with 500:100:250; result is Heavy Laser with 200:0:250

- probability of exploding of 75.00%(1-200/800): dice value of 0.30 comparing with 0.75: unit exploded.

result is Heavy Laser with 9:0:250

Rapid Fire:

- Cruiser doesn't have rapid fire against Heavy Laser.

**defender fires at attacker**

Heavy Laser with 9:0:250 fires at Cruiser with 2340:50:400; result is Cruiser with 2140:0:400

**remove ships and restore shields.**

Cruiser still has integrity, restore its shield.

Heavy Laser lost all its integrity, remove it from battle.

**The battle ended after 2 rounds with attacker winning.**

Comment: Please edit your post to make the main question a bit more clear and specific. (What exactly do you want to improve? Performance? Accuracy?)

Comment: just kill everyone in the first round.

Comment: Why would you want to run this algorithm more than once per battle? One battle is one run of the algorithm. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Sorry about not being clear. **This program's aim is to calculate the most probable outcome of a battle from some game**

Comment: This is a very interesting problem. Could you please specify in more detail how the damage done by a bomber is calculated when it attacks. Ie. if a bomber has a weapon power of 50, does that mean it will do exactly 50 damage to any unit it hits, which is then split between the shields and structural integrity?

Answer (score 3):

For such amounts of units I believe it would be valid to take a (sort of) statistical, generalized approach.

Just sum up all stats of units of given type, keep the counts, then calculate total damage, total defence, remove the amount of opponent's units that was destroyed by the damage as a percent of total defence.

I believe this is the approach used by Travian or other online strategy games. For such large numbers there is no effective way.

### Special cases

> If target's structural integrity is lower than 30% of its initial
>   value, it has the probability of
>   1-structuralIntegrity/baseStructuralIntegrity to explode

I believe you can use Gaussian distribution to determine the amount of extra-exploded units. The larger the `σ` value the larger the probability of destruction.

Other approach could be to destroy a percent of remaining vessels. How large a percent? Your choice.

> Rapid fire

Since you did not define rapid fire, I can't really advise. But I would suggest adding a special stage of combat which would take this into account. You can also simply increase the damage by a factor determined by the rapid fire probability.

Comment: How would you then calculate rapid fire? What happens to chance for being destroyed after each shot?

Comment: Rapid fire of 20 against target ship means that the attacking ship has (20-1)/20 probability to fire again. I would calculate them before runing the simulation. I'm not definig the rules. The game already exists and I'm trying to write a simulator for it.

Comment: BTW yes, Travian and some similar games (e.g. tribal wars) use this very approach you mentioned.
The game in question have probabilistic model so outcome varies from simulation to simulation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your simulation should try to represent each unit acting independently and simultaneously. If so you will need to be very careful how you implement your simulation of each round. You don't want player 1 to have an advantage by being able to weaken or destroy the opposition's units so that they are less able to retaliate just because their turn is second.  So all of the updating of the shields and integrity and explosions needs to be stored and applied after both players have made their moves.

When you run the simulation, you will get a result that one or the other player won that battle. By running it an arbitrary number of times, and calculating for player 1 the wins / (wins + losses) you will get an estimate of the percentage of times player 1 would win given the starting situation. This is similar to tossing a coin to determine if it is a fair coin (see wikipedia).

You can also calculate an estimator of the error and use this to determine the confidence interval. This gives you the range of values which would contain the true probability of player 1 winning the scenario an arbitrary percentage of the time (eg 95%). If you want to be extremely confident the range contains the true value and have a small margin of error the you will be in for a long night as you will need to run many simulations. You will also need more simulations if the battle is evenly matched rather than if it is more one-sided.

I've done some rough calculations as per the wikipedia article on tossing a fair coin.
If you are happy with a 95% confidence interval, and want the maximum error to be 0.01, then you need 10000 tests if the probability of winning is 50%. If it is only 25%, then you will need about 1350. If it is only 10% then you will only need 312. If you want the 99% confidence interval then you will need about 3 times as many tests.

EDIT

I think an analytical solution to this problem will be extremely difficult. I was going to suggest that you simplify your rules to make it more tractable.

Rule 3 - Requiring a minimum weapon power to attack a particular shield is unlikely to have much effect on whether any structural damage is done to a unit unless one side outnumbers the other by 100:1. Any small amount of damage done if this rule were not in place would be healed when the shields are restored at the end of the round. I suggest ignoring this rule.

Rule 6 - I think that if you have 100 blasters with a 10% chance of rapid fire, this is identical (from an average damage done to the enemy point of view) to having 110 blasters which don't rapid fire. So to calculate the effects of rapid fire, just increase the average damage done by the percentage chance of rapid fire.

Rule 5 - This significantly complicates the situation as now the variance of the structural integrity values now significantly affects how many units survive to the next round. Without this rule you could just work on using the average damage done per unit to estimate the amount of damage done to the enemy similar to the other suggestions given. If you wanted to simplify this, I think it would be similar to modelling units that have 30% less structural integrity 85% of the time, which works out to reducing all units integrity by 25.5%.

By doing this you will essentially be following Dariusz's approach

```
Eg if you have 
Side A: 100k bombers and 200k rocket launchers 
Side B: 130k bombers and 150k rocket launchers

Expected total damage side A (ETDa)
ETDa = 100k*BomberDamage*(1+rapidfire%bomber) + 200k*RLDamage*(1+rapidfire%rocketlauncher)

This will be spread evenly between the units in side B based upon their percentage of the total number of units present.

Expected total damage to bombers on side B (ETDBombersB)
ETDBombersB = 130k/280k*ETDa
Similarly ETDRocketLaunchersB = 150k/280k*ETDa

Structural damage to bombers on side B is reduced by the amount of the bombers shields
ESDBombersB = ETDBombersB - 130k*BombersShields
Similarly ESDRocketLaunchersB = ETDRocketLaunchersB - 150k*RocketLaunchersShields

Rather than have partly damaged units at the end of a round, I suggest you treat all existing units as fully healed, and apply the damage to units in turn until it is all used up. As above I am reducing the  structural integrity by 25.5% to model the average chance of explosion.
% of bombers destroyed = ESDBombersB / StructuralIntegrityBombers*(1-0.255)*130k
% of rocket launchers destroyed = ESDRocketLauncherB / StructuralIntegrityRL*(1-0.255)*150k
```

Also note that by the central limit theorem you are more likely to get the average result when you have a larger number of units in the simulation, the extreme amount of damage one unit does will tend to be cancelled out by the low amounts that others do. I.e. it is much more likely to get extreme values 1 or 6 on a dice when rolling it once, than it is to get a total of 3 or 18 when rolling it 3 times. So this may make the statistically fudged analysis still reasonably useful.

But if you are trying to simulate the situation in an actual existing game, then the rules are specified and you need to spend the time to work on a monte carlo simulation as originally described to get the most accurate result.

Comment: I've edited my question. Each round both players attack. The simulation goes like that: one side attacks, other side attacks, remove ships with no structural integrity, restore shields for the rest. So there is no difference in who starts the battle.